# Laravel logging email

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to somehow see the email log from my Laravel application? I have a contact form and some emails might be lost since the wrong email-address was set for a while, so I want to know if I can see who tried to email me?

Comment: Have you configured to store this data somewhere (which might be legally challenging according to GDPR or similar settings)? If not, I don't think there is any way. But you could really simply inspect your log file to check that on your own

Comment: Hmm no, I haven't configured to store the email data. Good point regarding GDPR. Do you mean to inspect the app/storage/logs/laravel.log files?

Comment: Well, wherever your logs are stored, inspect them

Answer (score 0):

The logs are found in application/storage/logs and the file is called:

> laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

For the wrong or invalid email the laravel `Email` class throw an error, so you have to catch it by using error handling methods i.e. `try` and `catch` like:

```
try
{
    // Email sending logic here
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Exception is catched here
    Log::info('save all the required data here so that you can check it later');    // This will log all the detail that you have passed here
}
```

Later on you can check the log to get all such entries for which email is failed.

Laravel logs are found in `application/storage/logs`